# How to determine whether the graph of a parametric equation is symmetric about the X-axis or the Y-axis？

Tags: calculus

How to determine whether the graph of a parametric equation is symmetric about the X-axis or the Y-axis **when** $y=f(x)$ **cannot be used to represent the equation**?

Such as:

> $x=\cos^3t$,$y=\sin^3t$

Comment: I think you can let $x_1 = 1$ and find the respective value of $t_1$ and with that find the value of $y_1$. Do the same for $x_2 = -1$ and find $y_2$ and if $y_1 = y_2$ then there is a symmetry  about the y-axis. Then do the same for the x-axis.

Comment: At least this works for the example you gave

Comment: It could be a coincidence.@EduudeE

Comment: if $x=f(t)$ and $y=g(t)$, you can define $t_a= f^{-1}(a)$, and then verify if $g(t_a)=g(t_{-a})$. If this is true for all $a$ then the function is symmetrical about the y-axis.

Comment: Symmetry about y - when for any x and -x you have the same value of y. since the values of cos t   and sin t   are not consistent with the sign, for same x you have have two values of  y and same goes the other direction. The symmetry of the above parametric is over  x and over y to the best of my understanding.